# matching search string with items from arraylist in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have :

```
string searchText = System.Console.ReadLine();

ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
```

I would like to filtering my Arraylist, I need find items that match i.e. first letter of items in collection

Comment: You can use simple for loop. Or you can also use linq contains. There are lot of ways to do that. See MSDN, you can find also lots of sample there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ArrayList` it's not strongly typed.You should instead look at using a strongly typed collection, such as `List<T>`:

```
string searchText = "text";//Hardcoded for the sake of example

List<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Add("text 1");
items.Add("hello");
items.Add("text 2");

foreach(string item in items)
{
    if(item.StartsWith(searchText))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();//Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this, however how to list only records thats match typed letter exacly i.e. last letter of word in collection what im trying to say is i want fillter i.e. names that contains 'a' letter as a last one in the string

Comment: Instead of StartsWith() use Contains()

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
 ArrayList lx = new ArrayList();
        lx.Add("ABCD");
        lx.Add("ABDM");
        lx.Add("AMFD");
        lx.Add("MXKK");

        ArrayList mx = new ArrayList();

        foreach (string x in lx) {
            if (x.Contains('A')) {
                mx.Add(x);
            }
        }


        foreach (string m in mx) {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

---

If you use List and LINQ the solution is:

```
        List<string> newStrings = new List<string>{
          "ABCD","ABDM","AMDF","XMKL"
        };

        List<string> lstA = newStrings.Where((s) => s[0] == 'A').ToList();
        foreach (string m in lstA) {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: both answers are right and I understand this, however how to compared exacly i.e. only first letter of the word in collection or last letter of word in collection

Comment: you will only change the condition thats all. if you want to search by last letter matched you should use:   List<string> lstM = newStrings.Where(s => s.EndsWith("L")).ToList(); . Or  if you want to search by first and last letter you should write:  List<string> lstAD = newStrings.Where(s => s.StartsWith("A") && s.EndsWith("D")).ToList();

Comment: Thanks guys @Tariqul Islam